# In the minted package, how do I enforce straight single quotes?

Tags: listings, punctuation, minted

Basically I want

```
\mint{python}|'banana'|
```

to produce straight single quotes, rather than the curly ones it normally produces (in `pdflatex`).

Comment: Not quite related to the q., but searching for the problem led me here:  Outside of verbatim, you can use \char18 and
\char13 to get modified ` and ' characters.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the package `upquote`. Note the package loads the package `textcomp`

The package `upquote` works also with `listings`.

```
% !TEX program  = pdflatex --shell-escape

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
\mint[fontfamily=tt]{python}|'banana'|
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

---

If you are using pygmentize version 1.6 that the package `upquote` can't do its job. To fix this issue you can use the following hack:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{upquote}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\def\PYZsq{\textquotesingle}%
}
\begin{document}
\mint[fontfamily=tt]{python}|'banana'|
\end{document}
```

Note if you are working with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX the hack isn't needed.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this later: the `upquote` package modifies all verbatim text (`\verb` and the `verbatim` environment) to render `'` and `\`` as the upright versions, not the “smart” `‘` and `’`.  Since (as I understand it) minted and listings rely on fancyvrb, which itself calls out to verbatim text under the hood, this has the desired effect.

Comment: On Mac OS 10.8.3 (if that matters), that still gives me curly quotes...

Comment: @Jubobs: Do you working with TL2013?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel This is embarrassing -_- but I'm not sure which version of TeX Live I have. How do I check that? Would the TeX Live Utility tell me that or do I need to type some code in the terminal?

Comment: @Jubobs: In the terminal you can do `latex -v`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks. *This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012).*

Comment: @Jubobs: We could locate the issue. When you use `xelatex` or `lualatex` it works. It seems this is a bug of pygmentize version 1.6. With version 1.2 it works.

Comment: @Jubobs: Please see my edit.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Works like a charm now. Thanks. You're a guru!

Comment: Did you intend to leave `\listfiles` in there?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Not really. It's a copy paste issue.

Comment: I find that the answer given here does not work in the presence of the `mathspec` package, either.

Comment: @brannerchinese: Using `mathspace` includes that you are compiling with XeLaTeX. In this case the package or the "hack" isn't necessary.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Compiling with XeLaTeX, I nonetheless see backticks converted to curly open single quote within `lstlisting` when used with `\upquote`.