# Minted+Inconsolata: Straight Quotes

Tags: fonts, punctuation, minted

I am using `minted` to display my source code and the Inconsolata package to set the output font. Unfortunately, this produces the following ugly result (note the direction of the quote marks:

[image: Example string with badly-shaped quote marks]

Figuring this was a bad attempt on LaTeX's part to use smart quotes, I tried using the `upquote` package. This produced the following:

[image: Example string which erroneously displays no quotes, using Inconsolata font]

Using this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{matlab}
    disp('This string should have straight quotes!');
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Removing the Inconsolata package produces a typographically-acceptable result, but, alas, not in the Inconsolata font:

[image: Example string with straight quotes, using tt font]

I'm not sure what's going on.

Why can't I have the font I want AND the appropriate quotes? Any thoughts?

Comment: The Inconsolata font doesn't have a straight quote character. `:(`

Comment: ... which the log file produced by your MWE tells you: `Missing character: There is no ' in font ts1-inconsolata!`.

Comment: An alternative is the Droid Sans Mono font (provided by `droidmono` package) which has straight quotes and looks somewhat similar.

Comment: @ChristianClason, does sourcecodepro shadow the `tt` font? Or how would I otherwise apply it to a `minted` environment?

Comment: Use `[fontfamily=fdm]` (for Droid Sans Mono, or `fvm` for Bera Sans Mono or `SourceCodePro-TLF` for SourceCode Pro) in the minted environment.

Comment: What the hell, Inconsolata! That font was *designed* for typesetting code. No straight quotes? The font designer was a master troll.

Comment: There's an [Inconsolata fork with straight quotes](http://nodnod.net/2009/feb/12/adding-straight-single-and-double-quotes-inconsola/), which you could [use with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/4012).

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 10):

The Inconsolata font doesn't have a straight quote character, as testified by the lines

```
Missing character: There is no ' in font ts1-inconsolata!
```

in your `.log` file. You can work around this by using the cmtt font and doing similarly to what `upquote` does:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`'=\active
\catcode``=\active
\g@addto@macro\@noligs
   {\def'{{\fontencoding{TS1}\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textquotesingle}}%
    \def`{{\fontencoding{TS1}\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\textasciigrave}}%
    }
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{matlab}
    disp('This string should have straight quotes!');
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe the quotes should be raised a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`'=\active
\catcode``=\active
\gdef\raise@quotes#1{\raisebox{.1ex}{\fontencoding{TS1}\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1}}
\g@addto@macro\@noligs
   {\def'{\raise@quotes{\textquotesingle}}%
    \def`{\raise@quotes{\textasciigrave}}%
    }
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{matlab}
    disp('This string should have straight quotes!');
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I know what `inconsolata.sty` doing here?

Comment: @MadyYuvi It’s not necessary, but it loads the font used by the OP.

Comment: Much thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 6):

There is (as of 2013-06-14) a new version of the `inconsolata` package by Michael Sharpe, called `inconsolata-zi4`, that provides a font with a straight quote which can be automatically used in verbatim environments (using `upquote`). (Currently, the new package has *replaced* `inconsolata` on CTAN, so use caution in updating; see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119925/16855).) With the new package, this works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[varqu]{zi4}%   updated inconsolata with variant upquotes
\AtBeginDocument{%         needed for pygmentize 1.6
\def\PYZsq{\textquotesingle}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[fontfamily=zi4]{matlab}
    disp('This string should have straight quotes!');
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(The `\def` to make `upquote` work with recent `pygments` is taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47451/16855).)

Comment: Good news! However, I'd have preferred if the package name had been kept, for backward compatibility.

Comment: The latest version (2013-07-13) now comes with an `inconsolata.sty` file for backward compatibility.