# Inconsolata missing after MiKTeX update

Tags: fonts, packages, miktex

I just ran the MiKTeX Updater and there was an update for Inconsolata. I also refreshed the FNDB and it is listed as installed in the Package Manager, but when I try to compile my documents that have `\usepackage{inconsolata}` I only get the error that `File 'inconsolata.sty' not found`.

How to fix this?

Comment: There is no `inconsolata.sty` on CTAN. The sty in the package is called `zi4`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Interesting. So, this is a MiKTeX database error using a wrong file name? edit: Yeah, If I change `\usepackage{inconsolata}` (that always worked and is also on the Font Catalogue) to `\usepackage{zi4}`, it works again...

Comment: No, miktex simply took what is on CTAN. The package has renamed its sty (I don't know why).

Comment: OK, thanks. As written in the edit to my last comment: `\usepackage{zi4}` makes it work again.

Comment: It seems that `inconsolata` (by Karl Berry) has been superseded by the new package (by Michael Sharpe). I'd say that a name change for the package (or an alias) would be welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a chat with the maintainer, and although it was not originally meant to replace the original package, another maintainer asked for the original package to be moved to obsolete.

What is also missing from the new package is the otf font.
here is what the maintainer said:

> I didn't include otf versions with the package because I intended this
>   to be a LaTeX support package. In rechecking the package details and
>   finding that the documentation did not recompile as I expected, I
>   found that I had omitted 3 files from the original package---the tfm's
>   and the fd for ts1 encoding, which contains the straight quotes. I'll
>   resend the corrected version to CTAN ASAP. All glyphs print correctly when using
>   both latex+dvips+ps2pdf and pdflatex workflows.
>
> [...]
>
> It was not written as a replacement, but became so after Karl Berry
>   suggested that he move his package to obsolete, where it is still
>   available and may be installed for your own use custom use.
>
> I'm not willing to include the otf fonts in my package because I don't
>   want to have to support them for use in LuaTeX and XeTeX. I suspect
>   they will require considerable massaging to be able to used except in
>   a very basic manner because, like the inconsolata ttf fonts from which
>   they were derived, they do not use unicode names exclusively, and they
>   contain no lookup tables.

I had an update from Karl Berry on the tex-live mailing list:

> the replacement of inconsolata was intentional.  In fact, it was my
>   suggestion (I had created the original package), since Michael's new
>   version seemed better in every way.  (He had indeed originally
>   uploaded it to CTAN as inconsolata-zi4.)
>
> I failed to realize that Michael's package omitted the otf's. 
>   Michael, would you mind including them?  I recognize the idea of
>   "LaTeX support", but still, seems much simpler to just include the
>   otf's than to have a whole separate package for them?  That way
>   everything is just there ...
>
> As for the .sty file name, I did see that the new package didn't have
>   inconsolata.sty, but I knew perfect compatibility was not going to be
>   plausible, so changing documents to use the new .sty name seemed the
>   best approach.  I wouldn't go that route in all cases, but this one is
>   not a core part of the system or anything.  If you need perfect
>   compatibility, probably just keeping the old inconsolata around is the
>   only viable way ...

Comment: I actually think this should have been handled in a much better way that would not break things. And dropping support for things like LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX is major regression. I'm not sure why support had to be dropped instead of simply keeping the old functionality working. The maintainer gave me a link to an otf version of zi4 but this doesn't stop the fact that functionality has been broken.

Comment: So, `\IfFileExists{zi4.sty}{\usepackage{zi4}}{\usepackage{inconsolata}}` is the (only) solution for now to create portable source files that use Inconsolata?

Comment: @krlmlr you should not have to resort to this when loading the package as an up to date version will offer both `zi4.sty` and `inconsolata.sty`. This was done back mid 2013 after a few complaints I think. As I reported in my answer, the package maintainer says that the old and new package have incompatibilities but I do not have a list of them. there are definitely new options in the new package but I don't know if options from the old one have different meaning in the new one.

Answer (score 6):

`inconsolata` was renamed without announcment to `zi4` for unknown(?) reasons, so changing all `\usepackage{inconsolata}` to `\usepackage{zi4}` solves the problem.

(Thanks to Ulrike Fischer in the comments for finding this out)