# Error: Font ts1-zi4r at 540 not found

Tags: r

I use MikTeX in order to compile pdf files when creating R packages.
Today I found out that I run into the following error:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file ts1-zi4r): Font ts1-zi4r at 540 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR
```

Any suggestion on how I might be able to fix this problem?

(this is after I've updated Rd.sty in R, following the [suggestion here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/inconsolata-sty-is-liable-to-disappear-texinfo-5-1-td4669976.html))

Thanks!

Comment: Try if it works if you run `updmap` on the command line.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem when using `\usepackage{zi4}` instead of `\usepackage{inconsolata}` as suggested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119925/inconsolata-missing-after-miktex-update, but unrelated to Rd (not using anything related to R). I don't know if I should open a separate question.

Comment: I just changed from \usepackage{zi4} to \usepackage{inconsolata} and got the error: LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
! LaTeX Error: File `inconsolata.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.281

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - could you please give more details? simply running updmap does not seem to do much.

Comment: Run this document: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\font\test=ts1-zi4r  \test \char95
\end{document}` with pdflatex. Does it work?

Comment: Hi Ulrike, I just ran it and got:
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file ts1-zi4r): Font ts1-zi4r at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
texify: pdflatex failed for some reason (see log file).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I got exactly the same error when running this document.

Comment: @wnstnsmth: Well it works fine for me on a current miktex and in texlive. And the error indicates that the map files are not up-to-date. So 1. run the update manager (in miktex as user + as admin) and check for update of inconsolata or zi4, 2. run updmap on the command line (as user). If it doesn't help run `updmap --verbose >updmap.log` and show the created log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I ran `mpm --admin --verbose --find-updates`, but couldn't find any package with name `inconsolata` or `zi4`. Then I ran `updmap` both as user and as admin, but I still get the same error. This is the `updmap` log: http://pastebin.com/Ucb7Ew5R

Comment: @wnstnsmth: I wrote: check for update as admin *and* as user. If you did install the package as user than you must also update it as user.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I actually tried both. This is the output for user http://pastebin.com/CW7jnzdK and this is the output for admin http://pastebin.com/6qmc84qX -- both look quite the same and I have no clue which package could be related to zi4 or inconsolata. The only thing I know is that the `inconsolata` package I installed (as user) yesterday was packaged on 2013-07-09.

Comment: It is a bit unusual imho that only one updmap.cfg is parsed. What do you get if you run `kpsewhich zi4.map`? And if you run `initexmf --report` where is the user install root?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9816/discussion-between-wnstnsmth-and-ulrike-fischer)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: This was likely due to some backward-incompatible changes to the `inconsolata` package, which has since been sorted out - the latest version on CTAN should be compatible again. Can you check if updating MikTeX now fixes the problem?

Comment: (Note that the patch described in the link is then no longer necessary.)

Answer (score 34):

I ran into this issue, and after some time spent banging my head against a post, I did reach a solution. After installing the package, run the following steps from inconsolata README. Open a `cmd` and run:

```
initexmf --update-fndb
initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
```

The latter command should open updmap.cfg in your default editor, commonly Notepad. Add the line below, then save and close.

```
Map zi4.map
```

Now in the command window, type

```
initexmf --mkmaps
```

Comment: Hallelujah I was banging my head against the wall for 3hrs with this.  Came across this post and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me. For users not so experienced: put line 1 and 2 in a windows console (cmd). Line 3 and 4 of the answer are description for you how to handle line 5. Line 6 is a description for you. Enter line 7 and you're done!

Answer (score 5):

In ubuntu, try to install

```
texlive-fonts-extra
```

for me, it did the trick.

## EDIT:

this problem is not specific to
windows/MikTeX. It's caused by the
engine used to compile R-help files.

In particular it will also happen if
you are using ubuntu (in my case 12.04,
with standard laTex install from the
ubuntu reps, e.g. no PPA).

The lines above solved the problem
for me.

Comment: The question was explicitly about MikTeX (which implies that he is using Windows, not Ubuntu).

Comment: However, a related problem exists in Ubuntu, which is solved by this answer.

Answer (score 4):

R 3.0.2 is normally completely compliant with the latest version of inconsolata (July 2013 or later), so if you still have problems, start with updating your TEX installation, your R installation and your TEX packages.

On a Windows machine with a MIKTEX installation, try the following steps :

- update R to at least R3.0.2 (that one is adapted for the new inconsolata package)
- update your MIKTEX installation to the latest version
- Run the update manager to make sure you have the latest version of inconsolata installed
- If you use a different account for administrator and user, **check if you don't have the inconsolata package installed twice** (once as administrator, once as user). If so, either delete one of both installations, or make sure both versions are updated to the latest.

I had an old version of inconsolata floating around in my user installation, which kept me busy for a couple of hours. [This post of Duncan Murdoch](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/35250) led me to the solution.

If all the above is OK, it should work without having to update Rd.sty or installing extra fonts on all main OS's.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I installed R, Rtools and MiKTeX in a Windows 8 machine. I followed the suggestions made in https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-June/066850.html, and installed the patched version of R-3.0.1. However the problem remained with the same message error.

The solution for me was just to uninstal the inconsolata package in the MiKTeX Package Manager, and then run the command `R CMD Rd2pdf --pdf mypackage` again, and it worked for me!

Best, Tonio

Comment: That is because you probably had 2 versions of the inconsolata package installed (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the link

> [suggestion here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/inconsolata-sty-is-liable-to-disappear-texinfo-5-1-td4669976.html)

does not work but I imagine it is the same solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856519/997979, as I got the same problem. When I run the command `updmap-user` I got the warning:

```
*************************************************************                                  
*                                                           *                                  
* WARNING: you are switching to updmap's per-user mappings. *                                  
*            Please read the following explanations.        *                                  
*                                                           *                                  
*************************************************************                                  
                                                                                               
You have run updmap-user (as opposed to updmap-sys) for the first time; this                                                            
has created configuration files which are local to your personal account.                      
                                                                                               
Any changes in system map files will *not* be automatically reflected in                       
your files; furthermore, running updmap-sys will no longer have any                                                                  
effect for you.  As a consequence, you have to rerun updmap-user yourself                      
after any change in the system directories; for example, if a new font                                              
package is added.                                                                              
                                                                                                                                        
See http://tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html for details.                                                                  
                                                                                               
If you want to undo this, remove the files mentioned above.
```

Looking at the referenced webpage I followed the suggestion of undo that and remove the files in `~/TEXMFVAR/fonts/map` and then, as I had already installed the package `texlive-fonts-extra`, I run as root `updmap-sys`.

Then, all worked nice.