# !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file t1-zi4r-0): Font t1-zi4r-0 at 540 not found

Tags: fonts, miktex, r, rstudio

My issue is same as this problem [Error: Font ts1-zi4r at 540 not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125274/error-font-ts1-zi4r-at-540-not-found/127977#127977?newreg=b70acdcf77ef471fbb44cbcdbaf3033b)

In my case, I am running Rstudio server on a remote machine for work. When trying to build the vignette/manual pdf I get this error. Since the Rstuido is not on my machine I am not sure how to run the solution commands on the remote server.
When I access the my server using ssh I am in my home folder. How do I install/update the miktex files there. I have miktex in my local system but that does not do anything. Also the solution provided in the other posts are windows specific. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Not idea with Rstudio servers, but I guess that if the PDF is generated by the server, the local system is irrelevant. As you are using a  remote system (maybe linux?) without root privileges, but with access to R, I will try first to install `tinytex` from R, not miktex. Well, .. really I will use another sans serif font and console myself thinking that nobody will care about, but that is another topic.

Answer (score 1):

R Studio Server uses LaTeX and the inconsolata font is missing (not found) in your LaTeX installation. Inconsolata is called: t1-zi4b.
To install, you can execute:

```
tlmgr install inconsolata
updmap-user
```

why updmap is needed? see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152721/problems-with-fonts/152749)

Rerefence:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524357/inconsolata-missing-to-build-r-vignette
(in @farid-cheraghi answer)

PS 1: another possible is to install the big (huge) `texlive-fonts-extra package` but you'll get unnecessary fonts and it takes space in your HDD.

PS 2: possibly this error occurs because R Studio uses Inconsolata found and this font was not included in LaTeX as before. Now you should install. Explanation here: https://texblog.net/latex-archive/fonts/inconsolata/

Comment: You should almost always `updmap-sys`, unless you’ve previously created a user font map, and then you should do both. The problem is that, instead of supplementing the system font map, [a user map hides the system map and prevents you from seeing any updates to it.](https://www.tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html)

Comment: On a multi-user system, I might need to install 8-bit fonts under my own home directory, and then I have no alternative but to `updmap-user` and keep it up-to-date. (For example, it’s possible to automatically check whether the user font map is out of date each time I log into Linux/Unix, the same way `make` does, or even in a project `Makefile`.) On my own box, though, I normally put all custom packages in TEXMFLOCAL and only run `updmap-sys`.