# Font Setup for an Academic Thesis, no Computer Modern Wanted

Tags: fonts

I want to help a friend to set up a template for his thesis.

So far I used the `lmodern` package for almost everything. But I think that the readability of computer modern on a screen is not really good (printed it is good). In addition `lmodern` or cm look very common because almost everyone uses it.

What font setup (math/text) would you recommend to spice a document up a little (it is still a academic thesis). It will be written in **German** and will contain a fair amount of **math** and **listings** too. It should look good on a screen too.

I once read that **Lucida Bright** is a great font regarding my demands. But it is **not free**. I also read that the The **LaTeX Companion** is written with Lucida Bright.

It is important that the math font contains **upright** and **italic greek letters**.

Listing to start:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Title}
\blindtext

\begin{description}
\item[serif] Test Test
\item[sans serif] \textsf{Test Test}
\item[typewriter] \texttt{Test Test}
\item[math] $a^2+b^2= c^2$
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Output with `\usepackage{lmodern}`

[image]

Output with `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`

[image]

Comment: What about `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`?

Comment: @moewe: Thanks for the comment. I want to see if there are other suggestions too. What is mathpazo known for?

Comment: You might also want to have a look at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`mathpazo` is a nice alternative, as suggested in a comment. My favorite alternative, however, is the LinuxLibertine family: Libertine for the serif font, Biolinum for the sans-serif, and the font is "complete" in the sense that you will have all the shapes you could wish (slanted, bold, small caps) as well as greek letters. You should definitely have a look at the `libertine` package.

**Edit:**
Useful comment from [Christian Clason](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16855/christian-clason): You can combine this with the `newtx` math fonts:

```
\usepackage[libertine,cmintegrals,cmbraces,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
```

and (if necessary) `inconsolata` for the monospace font

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{inconsolata}
```

**EDIT:** Be aware that on MiKTeX the package `inconsolata` has a new name and you need to call

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{zi4}
```

See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119925/inconsolata-missing-after-miktex-update).

Comment: You can combine this with the `newtx` math fonts: `\usepackage[libertine,cmintegrals,cmbraces,vvarbb]{newtxmath}`, and (if necessary) `inconsolata` for the monospace font: `\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{inconsolata}`.

Answer (score 10):

For my [PhD-Thesis](https://github.com/habi/PhD-Thesis) I used the (in my view awesome) [`classicthesis`](http://www.miede.de/#classicthesis), wich uses the Palatino, Euler and Bera Mono typefaces, which seemed like a nice choice.