# MiKTeX cannot download font

Tags: miktex, docker

I am trying to run MiKTeX in a docker container, but I'm having problems with few fonts. I've seen multiple mentions that I need to do updmap but there is no such command available. mpm --update-db exits silently but does not help with the issue.

Here's my Dockerfile, which is slightly modified version of official MiKTeX dockerfile from [here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/docker-miktex) :

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 python3-pip

RUN apt-get install -y \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        dirmngr \
        ghostscript \
        gnupg \
        gosu \
        make \
        perl

RUN apt-get clean

RUN echo 'Acquire::https::ctan.gust.org.pl::Verify-Peer "false";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99influxdata-cert

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889

RUN echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu focal universe" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list

RUN apt-get update -y \
    &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
           miktex

RUN    miktexsetup finish \
    && initexmf --admin --set-config-value=[MPM]AutoInstall=1 \
    && mpm --admin --update-db \
    && mpm --admin \
           --install amsfonts \
           --install biber-linux-x86_64 \
    && initexmf --admin --update-fndb

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/bin"

RUN pip install aiofiles pyside6

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
```

When I try compiling my .tex file to .pdf it crashes with following error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file t1-zi4b-0): Font t1-zi4b-0 at 480 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
pdflatex: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.
```

Trying out updmap as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280631/new-font-file-not-found-with-miktex-installation):

```
root@ee9497470950:/app# updmap --admin
bash: updmap: command not found
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: MiKTeX console , in the `Tasks` menu, has a  `Refresh font map files` item.

Comment: @Bernard not really an option for a Docker container, especially since I want the image to be automated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119925/inconsolata-missing-after-miktex-update?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment267189_119925%20?) (Inconsolata missing after MiKTeX update)?

TL;DR: Use `\usepackage{zi4}`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/220800)

Comment: Thank you @Willoughby! I'll try to keep this line while posting here :)