# Upright quote in equation

Tags: equations, punctuation

What I want to have are single quotes in an equation which are
just straight down like 'a'.
It seems that the default is somewhat italic like ´a´.

I found lots of example to change the fontstyles inline of a text but they
never affected the equation.

```
\begin{equation} sometext = 'abc' \end{equation}
```

produces:

> *sometext = ´abc´ (1)*

I need :

> sometext = 'abc' (1)

Comment: You probably want `\text{sometext}`, which requires `\usepackage{amsmath}` (or `mathtools`, good chance you have one of them in the preamble already).

Comment: this might be helpful: [In the minted package, how do I enforce straight single quotes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46880/579).  the `upquote` package is recommended.

Comment: thanks for your replies, \text{'a'} and \texttt{'a'} are working,
but if I have to insert them before every char declaration
like 'a', 'b', 'c' ... it is somewhat unintuitiv. 
Are there no options like \begin[fontstyle]{equation}\...{...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `'` is already taken for denoting, in math mode, a prime like in derivatives; in text mode it produces an apostrophe/right quote.

You can define a new math symbol font (if you have room for it}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for TS1
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{textsymbols}{TS1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{textsymbols}{bold}{TS1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\ulq}{\mathopen}{textsymbols}{39}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\urq}{\mathclose}{textsymbols}{39}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \log\ulq x \urq
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Otherwise a less efficient definition that spares a math group, but requires some more work for respecting `\boldmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for TS1
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ulq}{\mathopen{\textnormal{\textquotesingle}}}
\newcommand{\urq}{\mathclose{\textnormal{\textquotesingle}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \log\ulq x \urq
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want upright text in your equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\textnormal{sometext}=\ulq\textnormal{abc}\urq
\end{equation}
```

but this is a different thing than straight quotes.

Comment: what bothers me a bit about latex is the afford it
takes to put upright qoutes.

Comment: @jam Straight quotes are a leftover of typewriters, they have no real place in typography; they can have their usage, but I'd recommend using different symbols, if possible: there are `\ulcorner` and `\urcorner` (with `\usepackage{amssymb}`) that might do better.

Comment: For up-to-date releases of LaTeX, loading `textcomp` is no longer necessary

Answer (score 3):

[`upquote`](http://ctan.org/pkg/upquote) and [`textcomp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) can help here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{upquote,textcomp,amsmath}
\newcommand{\upquote}{\text{\textquotesingle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   f(x) = \upquote abc \upquote
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this:

```
\begin{equation} \text{sometext} = \text{'abc'} \end{equation}
```

Comment: To get the spacing right you'd want `\text{sometext} = \text{'abc'}`.

Comment: yes I think you suggest a better way