# Unicode characters missing when converting from jupyter to pdf via latex

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I have found that some unicode charaters in jupyter notebook are not being converted correctly when changing to pdf format.

[image: From PDF]

In the image above it shows the output from the converted pdf. In the image below it shows the original

[image: From jupyter notebook]

I have installed the texlive texlive-extra and pandoc packages. I have tried to do this with the pdflatex engine. The strangest part is that for the alpha greek letter does appear outside the code box but not inside it. Others like the theta are completely gone.

From the generated tex file i have found the following related to fonts

```
    \usepackage{iftex}
    \ifPDFTeX
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \else
        \usepackage{fontspec}
    \fi
```

In the following segment of code there is one example of the alpha that does appear and one that does not. It seems as if they are defined differently.

```
 \hypertarget{integrate-to-find-alpha_l0}{%
\subsection{\texorpdfstring{Integrate to find
\(\alpha_{L=0}\)}{Integrate to find \textbackslash alpha\_\{L=0\}}}\label{integrate-to-find-alpha_l0}}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, size=fbox, boxrule=1pt, pad at break*=1mm,colback=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]
\prompt{In}{incolor}{72}{\boxspacing}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PY{n}{α\PYZus{}rad} \PY{o}{=} \PY{o}{\PYZhy{}}\PY{p}{(}\PY{l+m+mi}{1}\PY{o}{/}\PY{n+nb}{π}\PY{p}{)}\PY{o}{*}\PY{n}{integrate}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{cc\PYZus{}f′}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{θ}\PY{p}{)}\PY{p}{,}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{θ}\PY{p}{,}\PY{l+m+mi}{0}\PY{p}{,}\PY{n}{middleLimit}\PY{p}{)}\PY{p}{)} \PY{o}{\PYZhy{}}\PY{p}{(}\PY{l+m+mi}{1}\PY{o}{/}\PY{n+nb}{π}\PY{p}{)}\PY{o}{*}\PY{n}{integrate}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{cc\PYZus{}r′}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{θ}\PY{p}{)}\PY{p}{,}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{θ}\PY{p}{,}\PY{n}{middleLimit}\PY{p}{,}\PY{n+nb}{π}\PY{p}{)}\PY{p}{)}
\PY{n}{α\PYZus{}deg} \PY{o}{=} \PY{n}{float}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{rad2deg}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{α\PYZus{}rad}\PY{p}{)}\PY{p}{)}

\PY{n}{println}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{α\PYZus{}rad}\PY{p}{)}
\PY{n}{println}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{α\PYZus{}deg}\PY{p}{)}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

    \usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{parskip} % Stop auto-indenting (to mimic markdown behaviour)
    
    \usepackage{iftex}
    \ifPDFTeX
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \else
        \usepackage{fontspec}
    \fi

    % Basic figure setup, for now with no caption control since it's done
    % automatically by Pandoc (which extracts ![](path) syntax from Markdown).
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    % Maintain compatibility with old templates. Remove in nbconvert 6.0
    \let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
    % Ensure that by default, figures have no caption (until we provide a
    % proper Figure object with a Caption API and a way to capture that
    % in the conversion process - todo).
    \usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{nocaption}{}
    \captionsetup{format=nocaption,aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

    \usepackage{float}
    \floatplacement{figure}{H} % forces figures to be placed at the correct location
    \usepackage{xcolor} % Allow colors to be defined
    \usepackage{enumerate} % Needed for markdown enumerations to work
    \usepackage{geometry} % Used to adjust the document margins
    \usepackage{amsmath} % Equations
    \usepackage{amssymb} % Equations
    \usepackage{textcomp} % defines textquotesingle
    % Hack from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47451/13684:
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \def\PYZsq{\textquotesingle}% Upright quotes in Pygmentized code
    }
    \usepackage{upquote} % Upright quotes for verbatim code
    \usepackage{eurosym} % defines \euro
    \usepackage[mathletters]{ucs} % Extended unicode (utf-8) support
    \usepackage{fancyvrb} % verbatim replacement that allows latex
    \usepackage{grffile} % extends the file name processing of package graphics 
                         % to support a larger range
    \makeatletter % fix for old versions of grffile with XeLaTeX
    \@ifpackagelater{grffile}{2019/11/01}
    {
      % Do nothing on new versions
    }
    {
      \def\Gread@@xetex#1{%
        \IfFileExists{"\Gin@base".bb}%
        {\Gread@eps{\Gin@base.bb}}%
        {\Gread@@xetex@aux#1}%
      }
    }
    \makeatother
    \usepackage[Export]{adjustbox} % Used to constrain images to a maximum size
    \adjustboxset{max size={0.9\linewidth}{0.9\paperheight}}

    % The hyperref package gives us a pdf with properly built
    % internal navigation ('pdf bookmarks' for the table of contents,
    % internal cross-reference links, web links for URLs, etc.)
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    % The default LaTeX title has an obnoxious amount of whitespace. By default,
    % titling removes some of it. It also provides customization options.
    \usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{longtable} % longtable support required by pandoc >1.10
    \usepackage{booktabs}  % table support for pandoc > 1.12.2
    \usepackage[inline]{enumitem} % IRkernel/repr support (it uses the enumerate* environment)
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % ulem is needed to support strikethroughs (\sout)
                                % normalem makes italics be italics, not underlines
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    

    
    % Colors for the hyperref package
    \definecolor{urlcolor}{rgb}{0,.145,.698}
    \definecolor{linkcolor}{rgb}{.71,0.21,0.01}
    \definecolor{citecolor}{rgb}{.12,.54,.11}

    % ANSI colors
    \definecolor{ansi-black}{HTML}{3E424D}
    \definecolor{ansi-black-intense}{HTML}{282C36}
    \definecolor{ansi-red}{HTML}{E75C58}
    \definecolor{ansi-red-intense}{HTML}{B22B31}
    \definecolor{ansi-green}{HTML}{00A250}
    \definecolor{ansi-green-intense}{HTML}{007427}
    \definecolor{ansi-yellow}{HTML}{DDB62B}
    \definecolor{ansi-yellow-intense}{HTML}{B27D12}
    \definecolor{ansi-blue}{HTML}{208FFB}
    \definecolor{ansi-blue-intense}{HTML}{0065CA}
    \definecolor{ansi-magenta}{HTML}{D160C4}
    \definecolor{ansi-magenta-intense}{HTML}{A03196}
    \definecolor{ansi-cyan}{HTML}{60C6C8}
    \definecolor{ansi-cyan-intense}{HTML}{258F8F}
    \definecolor{ansi-white}{HTML}{C5C1B4}
    \definecolor{ansi-white-intense}{HTML}{A1A6B2}
    \definecolor{ansi-default-inverse-fg}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
    \definecolor{ansi-default-inverse-bg}{HTML}{000000}

    % common color for the border for error outputs.
    \definecolor{outerrorbackground}{HTML}{FFDFDF}

    % commands and environments needed by pandoc snippets
    % extracted from the output of `pandoc -s`
    \providecommand{\tightlist}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
    \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
    % Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
    \newenvironment{Shaded}{}{}
    \newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.13,0.00}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textit{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.02,0.16,0.49}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{{#1}}
    
    % Additional commands for more recent versions of Pandoc
    \newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{\textit{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    \newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    \newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    \newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    
    
    % Define a nice break command that doesn't care if a line doesn't already
    % exist.
    \def\br{\hspace*{\fill} \\* }
    % Math Jax compatibility definitions
    \def\gt{>}
    \def\lt{<}
    \let\Oldtex\TeX
    \let\Oldlatex\LaTeX
    \renewcommand{\TeX}{\textrm{\Oldtex}}
    \renewcommand{\LaTeX}{\textrm{\Oldlatex}}
    % Document parameters
    % Document title
    \title{Untitled}
    
    
    
    
    
% Pygments definitions
\makeatletter
\def\PY@reset{\let\PY@it=\relax \let\PY@bf=\relax%
    \let\PY@ul=\relax \let\PY@tc=\relax%
    \let\PY@bc=\relax \let\PY@ff=\relax}
\def\PY@tok#1{\csname PY@tok@#1\endcsname}
\def\PY@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%
    \PY@tok{#1}\expandafter\PY@toks\fi}
\def\PY@do#1{\PY@bc{\PY@tc{\PY@ul{%
    \PY@it{\PY@bf{\PY@ff{#1}}}}}}}
\def\PY#1#2{\PY@reset\PY@toks#1+\relax+\PY@do{#2}}

\@namedef{PY@tok@w}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@c}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@cp}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@k}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kp}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kt}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.00,0.25}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@o}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ow}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nb}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nf}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nc}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nn}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ne}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.25,0.23}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nv}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@no}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nl}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ni}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.60,0.60,0.60}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@na}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nt}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nd}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@s}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sd}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@si}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@se}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sr}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ss}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sx}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@m}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gh}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gu}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gd}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gi}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gr}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ge}{\let\PY@it=\textit}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gs}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gp}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@go}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.53,0.53}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gt}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.27,0.87}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@err}{\def\PY@bc##1{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{\string -\fboxrule}\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{1,1,1}{\strut ##1}}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kc}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kd}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kn}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kr}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@bp}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@fm}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@vc}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@vg}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@vi}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@vm}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sa}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sb}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sc}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@dl}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@s2}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sh}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@s1}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mb}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mf}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mh}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mi}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@il}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mo}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ch}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@cm}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@cpf}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@c1}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@cs}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}

\def\PYZbs{\char`\\}
\def\PYZus{\char`\_}
\def\PYZob{\char`\{}
\def\PYZcb{\char`\}}
\def\PYZca{\char`\^}
\def\PYZam{\char`\&}
\def\PYZlt{\char`\<}
\def\PYZgt{\char`\>}
\def\PYZsh{\char`\#}
\def\PYZpc{\char`\%}
\def\PYZdl{\char`\$}
\def\PYZhy{\char`\-}
\def\PYZsq{\char`\'}
\def\PYZdq{\char`\"}
\def\PYZti{\char`\~}
% for compatibility with earlier versions
\def\PYZat{@}
\def\PYZlb{[}
\def\PYZrb{]}
\makeatother


    % For linebreaks inside Verbatim environment from package fancyvrb. 
    \makeatletter
        \newbox\Wrappedcontinuationbox 
        \newbox\Wrappedvisiblespacebox 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedvisiblespace {\textcolor{red}{\textvisiblespace}} 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedcontinuationsymbol {\textcolor{red}{\llap{\tiny$\m@th\hookrightarrow$}}} 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedcontinuationindent {3ex } 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedafterbreak {\kern\Wrappedcontinuationindent\copy\Wrappedcontinuationbox} 
        % Take advantage of the already applied Pygments mark-up to insert 
        % potential linebreaks for TeX processing. 
        %        {, <, #, %, $, ' and ": go to next line. 
        %        _, }, ^, &, >, - and ~: stay at end of broken line. 
        % Use of \textquotesingle for straight quote. 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedbreaksatspecials {% 
            \def\PYGZus{\discretionary{\char`\_}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\_}}% 
            \def\PYGZob{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\{}{\char`\{}}% 
            \def\PYGZcb{\discretionary{\char`\}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\}}}% 
            \def\PYGZca{\discretionary{\char`\^}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\^}}% 
            \def\PYGZam{\discretionary{\char`\&}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\&}}% 
            \def\PYGZlt{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\<}{\char`\<}}% 
            \def\PYGZgt{\discretionary{\char`\>}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\>}}% 
            \def\PYGZsh{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\#}{\char`\#}}% 
            \def\PYGZpc{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\%}{\char`\%}}% 
            \def\PYGZdl{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\$}{\char`\$}}% 
            \def\PYGZhy{\discretionary{\char`\-}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\-}}% 
            \def\PYGZsq{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\textquotesingle}{\textquotesingle}}% 
            \def\PYGZdq{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\"}{\char`\"}}% 
            \def\PYGZti{\discretionary{\char`\~}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\~}}% 
        } 
        % Some characters . , ; ? ! / are not pygmentized. 
        % This macro makes them "active" and they will insert potential linebreaks 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedbreaksatpunct {% 
            \lccode`\~`\.\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\.}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\.}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\,\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\,}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\,}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\;\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\;}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\;}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\:\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\:}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\:}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\?\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\?}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\?}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\!\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\!}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\!}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\/\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\/}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\/}}}% 
            \catcode`\.\active
            \catcode`\,\active 
            \catcode`\;\active
            \catcode`\:\active
            \catcode`\?\active
            \catcode`\!\active
            \catcode`\/\active 
            \lccode`\~`\~   
        }
    \makeatother

    \let\OriginalVerbatim=\Verbatim
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\Verbatim}[1][1]{%
        %\parskip\z@skip
        \sbox\Wrappedcontinuationbox {\Wrappedcontinuationsymbol}%
        \sbox\Wrappedvisiblespacebox {\FV@SetupFont\Wrappedvisiblespace}%
        \def\FancyVerbFormatLine ##1{\hsize\linewidth
            \vtop{\raggedright\hyphenpenalty\z@\exhyphenpenalty\z@
                \doublehyphendemerits\z@\finalhyphendemerits\z@
                \strut ##1\strut}%
        }%
        % If the linebreak is at a space, the latter will be displayed as visible
        % space at end of first line, and a continuation symbol starts next line.
        % Stretch/shrink are however usually zero for typewriter font.
        \def\FV@Space {%
            \nobreak\hskip\z@ plus\fontdimen3\font minus\fontdimen4\font
            \discretionary{\copy\Wrappedvisiblespacebox}{\Wrappedafterbreak}
            {\kern\fontdimen2\font}%
        }%
        
        % Allow breaks at special characters using \PYG... macros.
        \Wrappedbreaksatspecials
        % Breaks at punctuation characters . , ; ? ! and / need catcode=\active     
        \OriginalVerbatim[#1,codes*=\Wrappedbreaksatpunct]%
    }
    \makeatother

    % Exact colors from NB
    \definecolor{incolor}{HTML}{303F9F}
    \definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}
    \definecolor{cellborder}{HTML}{CFCFCF}
    \definecolor{cellbackground}{HTML}{F7F7F7}
    
    % prompt
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\boxspacing}{\kern\kvtcb@left@rule\kern\kvtcb@boxsep}
    \makeatother
    \newcommand{\prompt}[4]{
        {\ttfamily\llap{{\color{#2}[#3]:\hspace{3pt}#4}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    }
    

    
    % Prevent overflowing lines due to hard-to-break entities
    \sloppy 
    % Setup hyperref package
    \hypersetup{
      breaklinks=true,  % so long urls are correctly broken across lines
      colorlinks=true,
      urlcolor=urlcolor,
      linkcolor=linkcolor,
      citecolor=citecolor,
      }
    % Slightly bigger margins than the latex defaults
    
    \geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
    
    

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    

    
    \hypertarget{change-of-coordinate-system}{%
\subsection{Change of coordinate
system}\label{change-of-coordinate-system}}

To be able to solve the equations it is necessary to perform a cordinate
change from x to \(\theta\).

    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, size=fbox, boxrule=1pt, pad at break*=1mm,colback=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]
\prompt{In}{incolor}{4}{\boxspacing}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PY{k}{using} \PY{n}{SymPy}
\PY{n}{θ} \PY{o}{=} \PY{n}{Sym}\PY{p}{(}\PY{l+s}{\PYZdq{}}\PY{l+s}{θ}\PY{l+s}{\PYZdq{}}\PY{p}{)}

\PY{n}{varChange} \PY{o}{=} \PY{l+m+mf}{0.5}\PY{p}{(}\PY{l+m+mi}{1} \PY{o}{\PYZhy{}} \PY{n}{cos}\PY{p}{(}\PY{n}{θ}\PY{p}{)}\PY{p}{)}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}
 
            
\prompt{Out}{outcolor}{4}{}
    
    $\begin{equation*}0.5 - 0.5 \cos{\left(θ \right)}\end{equation*}$


    

    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, size=fbox, boxrule=1pt, pad at break*=1mm,colback=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]
\prompt{In}{incolor}{ }{\boxspacing}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]

\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}


    % Add a bibliography block to the postdoc
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: if you want any help you should provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. We have no idea which unicode char you are using and therefore a copyable example makes it easier for others to test and verify/solve your problem. It should be a full example, not these sniplets, somethng we can copy and use as is

Comment: when you run this you get an error `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character θ (U+03B8)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.` (which is theta)

Comment: and `! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.` as you have `\begin{equation*}` in `$...$`

Comment: Generic question: [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character θ (U+03B8)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

means that theta is not set up so:

```
    \ifPDFTeX
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{mathpazo}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B8}{\ensuremath{\theta}}
    \else
        \usepackage{fontspec}
    \fi
```

and

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.403     $\begin{equation*}
                            0.5 - 0.5 \cos{\left(θ \right)}\end{equation*}$
?
```

is because `equation*` has been started in math mode, delete the spurious `$`

```
    \begin{equation*}0.5 - 0.5 \cos{\left(θ \right)}\end{equation*}
```

The document then runs without error. Note don't ignore errors it is not worth looking at the genrated PDF if you get errors from LaTeX, and if asking for help it's better to show the error message rather than the pdf output.